# (OOP Technique) Inheritance vs. Interface --- same concept?--- (CSS Technique) styling tags vs. styling classes?

Tags: css, oop, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

Forgive that crazy title...

I'm trying to understand the concept of Inheritance vs Interface in object oriented programming. So I'm trying to relate it to something I know already, which is CSS.

In CSS, you can choose to style in a hierarchy that allows elements to "inherit" a style:

*(Like inheritance in OOP?)*

```
    a   { color:red; text-decoration:underline; }
    p   { background:black; color:white; padding:20px; } 
    img { background:silver; padding:2px;  }
```

or, style with .class (which is a better practice):

```
    .main-links      { color:red; text-decoration:underline; } 
    .main-paragraphs { background:black; color:white; padding:20px; }
    .main-images     { background:silver; padding:2px;  }
```

*(Like interface in OOP?)*

### My question is:

Is this same concept in CSS similar to Inheritance vs. Interface (for OOP)? Or do I have the complete wrong idea.

Comment: In OOP, classes are declared (such as using the "class" keyword) and can inherit multiple classes/interfaces
but every allocated instance inherits exactly the same as every other instance of the class.
In CSS, class instances (as created by the "class" attribute) can inherit independent sets of classes.
CSS inheritance is totally different from OOP inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You have the **completely** wrong idea. There is **absolutely no way** one can explain OOP inheritance / interface to you using CSS.

Inheritance and interfaces are programming concepts (very fundamental design patterns) while CSS is not a programming language (not turing complete).

There are plenty of very easy-to-follow tutorials / articles online that will give you a good understanding of both concepts. I recommend you read them.

*EDIT*: Well, on second thoughts, maybe, just maybe, inheritance could *sort of* be explained using CSS. Just as style properties cascade in CSS, class methods and properties 'cascade' down to derived classes. However, you'd be much better off reading an introductory tutorial than attempting to understand these concepts via CSS.

Comment: I totally understand that CSS is not a programming language ;)  , but the art of cascading styles is a similar concept of inheritance in OOP. Interfaces is what was really throwing me for a loop. like an interface in OOP, you can define "universal methods" for certain classes to use (right?) and like CSS classes you define a "universal style". When said like that can it be viewed in the same light?

Comment: Inheritance and interfaces are used in OOP for polymorphism, a concept that does not exist in CSS. Interfaces are much more than just defining 'universal methods'. If that were the case, you could achieve that using composition, inheritance, singletons etc.

Comment: Well on one hand css is actually Turing complete, and on the other hand turing completeness has nothing at all to do with inheritence or being a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare OOP to CSS, you will find that you can compare interfaces to styles, but there is nothing like inheritance in CSS.

Interfaces in OOP works pretty much as applying classes to an element. In the same way that you can add several classes to an element to combine different looks, you can add several interfaces to a class to combine different behaviours.

If you would have inheritance in CSS, it would be something like this:

```
.main-links { color: red; }

.info-links { @inherits: .main-links; font-weight: bold; }
```

Here one rule would inherit another, so that you could apply only the class `info-links` to an element to also get the implementation for `main-links`.

(Of course this wouldn't work in CSS, as the rules doesn't have names but selectors, and the selectors doesn't even have to be unique so they can't be used to identify a rule.)

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding you when you say "there is nothing like inheritance in css" because that's the one concept i felt like i had down w/ the comparison of OOP and CSS. checkout this fiddle i just put together, http://jsfiddle.net/GV2QX/2/ , when thinking of parent to child inheritance for Classes, it seems like the same goes for parent to child inheritance for Elements.

Comment: @MrRioku: Yes, if you see the HTML hierarchy as the class inheritance, then the CSS cascading would be similar to inheriting class members.